# PHP: Number of bytes in a string, raw HTTP

Tags: php, string

I am trying to get the number bytes in a PHP string. I seem to be running into a problem trying to send raw HTTP requests (PROPFIND, REPORT), and getting the proper length of the content. From which point, following the headers, do I start counting the content? And at which point, do I stop?

Comment: I didn't understand much, but if it doesn't have to do with dynamic content, you may want to just read the `Content-Length` header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You count the complete content, starting after the two linebreaks that delimit the header section:

```
$contentlength_bytes = strlen(strstr($http, "\r\n\r\n")) - 4;
```

If you're doing it that way already i guess you might have run into problems with encoding...

When your content has multibyte characters, using `strlen()` to return it's bytelength might not work correctly as multibyte characters might get interpreted as one byte under certain system configurations (see edit below - and comments for that part).

This will give you the correct bytelength of any content-string you feed it under any system configuration:

```
$contentlength_bytes = mb_strlen(strstr($http, "\r\n\r\n"), 'latin1') - 4;
```

**Edit:**
As Jon pointed out in the comments, this is not always needed as `strlen()` will return the correct bytecount of a string in most circumstances.

I just added this method of measuring as on multibyte systems and under certain circumstances (for example `mbstring.func_overload` set to 2) `strlen()` is not safe to use against binary strings.

The above method is the only known (to me) way to completely binary safe calculate the byte-length of a given string. And i tripped over this a couple of times already..

Comment: `latin1` only contains 8byte characters, that's why. You can use any single-byte character charset for this. The `Content-Type` headers don't matter for this as you need to specify content length in bytes, not characters. PHP is a little stubborn when it comes to determine a byte length for a string. That's all that's behind this workaround. It's just a multibyte safe version of `strlen()` that will always give you bytelength regardless of encoding.

Comment: -1: **This is factually wrong.** Multibyte characters will be counted as multiple bytes with pure `strlen`, that's how that function works. You only need `mb_strlen` if you want the *character length*.

Comment: @Jon: wrong - `strlen()` is not always safe to use - for example see this problem i found when poking google with this: http://php.bigresource.com/size-of-binary-string-on-multi-byte-system--PAWEYTMl.html - i had this issue myself a couple of times. `strlen()` is only safe to use as long as you are working in a single byte encoded environment. Using `mb_strlen` with explicit 8byte charset is the only binary safe way to do this. (Except from writing to a file and using `filesize()`). Using `strlen()` on systems with enabled `mbstring.func_overload = 2` is also unsafe and will return chars.

Comment: I know about those options (and have answered questions regarding them). But I do not accept this argument because by the same token, any code posted here that does not take into account the possibility that `magic_quotes_gpc` is on would be buggy. Those options are not standard configuration, so if you *do* enable them you should be aware of the changes in behavior. To say that `strlen` does not work because *there is an option* that makes it not work does not sit well with me. Also note that both those cases involve using "compatibility hacks" as the lesser evil.

Comment: This is not an argument, this is just my experience since i had this issue myself already. This answer was meant and formulated to be a "if you are already doing it the correct way, try this as your system configuration might be affecting strlen" type of additional hint. Sorry if that hasn't been very clear, i edited a little bit into the answer.

Comment: Downvote removed since the answer is better now. But it would be even better if an edit was made at the "using strlen to return..." part, and also if it tackled the "how do I know where the content starts?" part of the question.

Comment: I think i broke my own record for edits on a single post on this one... happy now? :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have your entire request in a variable, say `$request`, then:

```
list($headers,$body) = explode("\r\n\r\n",$request,2);
```

Basically, the two CRLFs mark the end of the headers, and the contents start after that.

Comment: That's a good fact to rely upon (and it sounds like the right answer as well).